# Not allow user to change email on Stripe Checkout Session

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe for my app subscription needs. I have some webhooks which are called when an invoice is paid, failed etc now this webhooks send the customer_email and i use that to do some other tasks. Now the problem is that a user is able to change the email on checkout_session

[image]

I don't want the user to be able to change this. I tried disabling the option from the customer-portal dashboard on stripe but that didn't work either.

[image]

Changing this email calls the webhook with wrong email resulting in lost subscription etc. I can't seem to find the option to disable this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot disable changing the email address in the Checkout Session. You would probably want to use the customer's id as the unique reference (instead of relying on the customer's email).

Disabling the ability to update their email address as shown in the second screenshot, only disables that function in the [customer portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal).